# How to handle <br> </br> and <br/> in Beautiful Soup 4?

Tags: python, html, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to use python and Beautiful Soup 4 to replace every break tag in some html with a new line.

The document has `<br>`, `<br/>` and `</br>` tags in it, but because of how Beautiful Soup handles tags, whenever it finds a `<br>`, it removes everything between it and the next `</br>` it sees.

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 2):

Try using an `HTMLParserTreeBuilder` for the builder class:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4.builder import HTMLParserTreeBuilder

html_doc = """
<html>this is a test<br> ...between a start and end br... </br> a blank br: <br/> something else
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, builder=HTMLParserTreeBuilder())
print soup.prettify()
```

Compare the output when no `builder=` parameter is given.

You can determine which builder bs4 is using with:

```
print type(soup.builder)
```

By default it seems that bs4 chooses a builder based on lxml.